# Block iframe auto-resizing in ios

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, resize

I've found many threads about this issue, but none with a similar issue like I have, but I've tried those solutions anyway and they all failed.

**My situation:** I'm trying to incorporate a scrolling website into another website, using an iframe. This is working flawlessly with a normal setup on every devices except iOS with this basic code:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<style>
iframe{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   border:none;
}
</style>
```

On iOS however they are apparently forcing their way of auto-resizing. So the iframe auto-resizes to the length of the page.

Due to this behaviour, just using 1 finger I can scroll trough the page, but when clicking on anchor-links, that uses js for an animated scroll, fails.

I finally figured out that this is caused by the auto-resizing of iOS. Because the height of the content inside the iframe is being matched, the iframe itself doesn't have a scrollbar, but the parent does. And the javascript of the site won't control the parent-window but just it's own DOM(limited to the iframe as both sites live on different domains).

All the "solutions" I've found concerning the auto-resizing of iframes, where fixed using either a div to constraint the visible height of the iframe, and adding scrolling to that div or adding a scrolling="no" attribute. The second option results in no scrollbar being present at all, disabling the normal scrolling behaviour inside the iframe, but on the plus-side the anchor-links do work.

Is there any solution that allows both? 
Or am I just stuck with this, and can we really consider this being a bug inside ios-safari?